# In MongoDB, how to perform query based on if one string field contains another

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hello please help me with this.
In mongodb, I have a collection like this:

```
data1= {
    "string1":"abc",
    "string2":"abcde"
}

data2= {
    "string1":"abc",
    "string2":"ftgr"
}
```

After the query I only want to return data1 because it's `string2` property contains the contents of it's `string1` property. How can I make this work? Should I use $where or using regex? Very very appreciated if someone can point a tip.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me if you want a query to do this, or if you want to filter the results after the query is finished.

Comment: Also, it looks like this has been answered here using either $where or an aggregation: https://www.codeschool.com/discuss/t/how-to-query-based-on-the-variable-value-stored-in-another-field/20979/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `$where` by creating a `RegExp` for `string1` and then testing it against `string2`:

```
db.test.find({$where: 'RegExp(this.string1).test(this.string2)'})
```

However, if you're using MongoDB 3.4+ you can do this more efficiently by using the [`$indexOfCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/#exp._S_indexOfCP) aggregation operator:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    // Project  the index of where string1 appears in string2, along with the original doc.
    {$project: {foundIndex: {$indexOfCP: ['$string2', '$string1']}, doc: '$$ROOT'}},
    // Filter out the docs where the string wasn't found
    {$match: {foundIndex: {$ne: -1}}},
    // Promote the original doc back to the root
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$doc'}}
])
```

Or more directly by also using `$redact`:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: { $eq: [{$indexOfCP: ['$string2', '$string1']}, -1]},
            then: '$$PRUNE',
            else: '$$KEEP'
        }
    }}
])
```